# Similarity between “Caro nome che il mio cor” and “Celeste Aida”

Tags: chord-progressions, analysis, opera

While listening to [*Caro nome che il mio cor*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caro_nome_che_il_mio_cor) from [*Rigoletto*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigoletto) a couple days ago, I found a couple measures that reminded me vaguely of [*Celeste Aida*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Celeste_Aida) from [*Aida*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aida).

What do these two passages have in common, if anything? Also, is there any other passage from *Aida* with a closer resemblance to this passage from *Caro nome del mio ben*?

### Caro nome che il mio cor [(audio)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K8cTVQMihyI&t=201s)

[image: Caro nome che il mio cor]

### Celeste Aida [(audio)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8rsOzPzYr8&t=658s)

[image: Celeste Aida]

Comment: Do the beginning moments of either of these also sound to you like the above excerpts? 1) [Brahms Op. 119 No. 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bxaSYZHbVP0); 2) [Beethoven Op. 109](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qqSetFrR-Xo)

Comment: Not enough, albeit I can't explain why

Comment: The thirds bouncing up and down in the 1st passage with chromatic "aberrations" immediately brought to my mind Rachmaninoff Op. 38 No. 4 The pied piper ('The Rat-catcher') / Крысолов https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LWsgoOWgBuU&ab_channel=VictorNikolaev

Comment: and lol I found it hard to hear the quiet orchestra staccato chords underneath Pavarotti's "pianissimo, morendo" high B-flat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare the harmonies: `C - G - Am - E - G - D - C - E` (in E major) (starting from the voice entry) and `Gb - Bbm - Ebm - Bb - Eb` (in Bb major) you will find that both passages rely quite a bit on altered mediants. This means: In E major you do not get C-major, you get C# minor. You do not get G major, but G# minor. Similarly in Bb major you do not get Gb major, but G minor, you do not get Eb minor, but Eb major. This extended tonality gives a very specific color.

You get some more similarilties: Both passages move harmonically primarily in mediants and 4ths/5ths. Both passages have a bass that moves in somewhat alternating steps and falling 4ths. Such things.

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept this answer, although I was really hoping to find an exact match of that _Caro nome_ passage in other fragments of Aida. Maybe it's a _déjà entendu_, but I was really convinced that I heard that in other place before.